# How to take last row from Google Spreadsheet to the MIT App Inventor App?

Tags: android, google-sheets, app-inventor

I made very similar solution by using *Javascript* in HTML document. Basicaly javascript code take **last row (last data)** from the Google Spreadsheet to the HTML page. So the page is always up to date.

Now I try to make similar thing by MIT App Inventor. Maybe **ActivityStarter** can solve it. On the internet there is no solution. So it'd be great if we find something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the `Activity Starter`

You have 2 possibilities

1. you can adjust your HTML/JavaScript solution and use it together with the `Webviewer` component. Just return the result back to App Inventor in the `WebViewString` property, see also [How does the property Webviewer.WebViewString work?](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2webviewstring), or
2. use the `Web` component together with the [Google Visualisation API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage?hl=en), see also [my example here](https://puravidaapps.com/spreadsheet.php#select)

**Edit:** If you want to follow #2, then probably the easiest way is to add another datetime column and sort the result by that column to get only the last row as result (assuming, that datetime column is column A), see again the [Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage?hl=en):

```
ORDER BY A DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Dear Taifun, I got how to do it but I have a question. We can take a row into the app. It's ok. If we add a row in every 15 mins  how can we take last row?. I'll put the 'Update Button' to update but I don't know how to take last row always. You may explained in your example but I have no idea how. Thanks..

Comment: Instead of saying "Thank you": [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). See my updated answer.